# Why does my perl program that works in windows not work in mountain lion on my mac?

Tags: regex, windows, macos, perl

I have written a perl program which reads some data (the data are names which include alphanumeric characters which are split by an underscore, such as SDF_233), I read that data in using

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $file = "names.txt";
open(DATA,$file);
my @lines=<DATA>;
close DATA;

foreach my $line (@lines) {
my $name = $line; 
my $otherdata;  ...some more code...

print $name . "," . $otherdata;}
```

I print `$name` so that I can use it as a reference to double check the program has gone through every name when I compare back to the original list.

Q: This works on windows - I tried the same thing on my Mac but it doesn't work. I get no output for `$name`, but `$otherdata` does print - why is this? Does the underscore have something to do with this?

Comment: My guess is that you're getting bitten by line endings here. Since when you're reading the file, you're not clearing the line endings, you might end up with a `\r` in there in some environments, which would cause `$otherdata` to overwrite the `$name`. Try adding a `chomp $name` before you do anything else with it.

Comment: What Perl versions? What Mac version? What data do you put into the script, what do you get as output, and what do you expect? What encodings are you using? Where do you split your data?

Comment: While debugging, it is a very good idea to make use of the [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3A%3ADumper) module to see exactly what is in your variables. E.g. `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $name;`. In your case, there might be some whitespace in your string that is messing things up, the `Useqq` option will print that whitespace (and other escape sequences) literally, e.g. `\r\n\0` etc.

Comment: i actually had a chomp line of code i forgot to include in my example which was at the start of the foreach loop which was chomp($line), if i remove it completely, it now does print $name, but it includes a newline character, so it prints $otherdata on a separate line - if i now insert a chomp $name before i print the last line, again it just disappears...?

Comment: so if i remove it, it prints on separate lines, but i would like it all on the same line - how do i do that?

Comment: @user1637359 The line endings are different for mac and windows. You can do `$line =~ s/[\r\n]$//g` to remove all such characters. Your problem is probably due to using the same input file for different operating systems.

Comment: @TLP, You wouldn't remove CR LF, which he surely has. `$line =~ s/\s+\z//;` is much better.

Comment: @ikegami `\s` is a larger character class than is needed, though. Besides, isn't CR LF `\r` and `\n`?

Comment: @TLP, If your format includes the concept of significant trailing whitespace, you're nuts. When's the last time you wanted to keep trailing whitespace? /// Yes, CR is \r and LF is \n, but you only replace one of them when the input is "foo\r\n".

Comment: @ikegami Ah yes, can't use `/g` there. However `s/[\r\n]+$//` would work. It is not my place to question what value trailing whitespace has, but stripping it would be doing more than `chomp` would imply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code surely has a `chomp` you didn't show. If so, the problem is that your data file is formatted for Windows. Specifically, its lines are terminated with CR LF. On Windows, that would get changed to LF automatically, which you later remove with `chomp`. On your Mac, that conversion does not occur, so you leave the CR behind. Your code outputs

```
name\r,otherdata
```

which your terminal displays as

```
,otherdata
```

The solution is to fix your input file

```
dos2unix names.txt
```

or to change

```
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
   chomp($line);
   ...
}
```

to

```
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
   $line =~ s/\s+\z//;
   ...
}
```

PS - You shouldn't use a handle named DATA. Perl already creates one named that, so it's confusing.

PS - Use `s/[\r\n]+\z//` if you're in the weird situation that you must keep trailing whitespace.

Comment: `s/[\r\n]+\z//` otherwise you risk stripping spaces or tabs that should not be stripped.

Comment: yeah - i did have a chomp in there - i forgot to add it (mentioned this in the other comments - thanks!

Comment: @TLP, `s/[\r\n]+\z//` would risk not stripping trailing spaces and tabs that should be stripped. `s/\s+\z//` is the rule, and `s/[\r\n]+\z//` is the exception that you should never have to use. Anyway, added a note about that in the answer.

Comment: Or `open(DATA,'<:crlf',$file);` to do CRLF -> LF processing on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Like all the others, I assume you are having line ending problems. The way I would diagnose it if this were my script would be…

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use Data::Dumper; # My favorite debugging tool

my $file = "names.txt";
open(DATA,$file);
my @lines=<DATA>;
close DATA;
print Dumper(\@lines);

foreach my $line (@lines) {
    my $name = chomp $line; 
    print Dumper(\$name, \$line);
    my $otherdata;  

    #...some more code...

    print Dumper(\$otherdata);
    print $name . "," . $otherdata;
}
```